# getInitialProps in Next.js does not get data from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js

I am following [Next.js tutorial for fetching data](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages)

But unlike tutorial, I use `axios`. Problem is `getInitialProps` does not get the data I want to have.

here is the code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import Link from "next/link";

const Body = props => (
  <div>
    <h1>Shows</h1>
    <ul>
      {props.data.map(({ show }) => (
        <li key={show.id}>
          <Link as={`/p/${show.id}`} href={`/post?title=${show.title}`}>
            <a>{show.name}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
);

Body.getInitialProps = async function() {
  const res = await axios.get("https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=batman");
  const data = await res.data;
  console.log(`Show data fetched. Count: ${data.length}`);
  return {
    data: data
  };
};

export default Body;
```

To me, the code seems fine but error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` keeps occurring.

Comment: Does your API response has any errors?

Comment: just found another error at the top of the console saying "Fetch API cannot load..... URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

It occurred because I broke a simple rule.

According to [next.js document](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle), there is a note saying

**Note: `getInitialProps` can not be used in children components. Only in `pages`.**

So when I fetcehd that data at `index.js`, it successfully get the data I want to have.

Thought I could use `getInitialProps` in any components just like `componentDidMount`.

That was a problem.

Comment: Can you help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644618/why-the-data-not-displayed-in-nextjs

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong and, if I am, tell me and I will delete my answer but I think this is because you don't have a default value for that prop and the method that gets the data is not called immediately so there is a moment where your prop is `undefined` and you are calling `map` on an undefined prop.