# Why the data not displayed in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am making a very very simple nextjs application where I am trying to fetch the data from api.

My requirement is I should display the data in `layout.js` file and this `layout.js` file is a children in `index.js` file.

**index.js**:

```
import Layout from "./layout";
import React from "react";

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout />
        <h4> Main content will be displayed here !! </h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

**layout.js**:

```
import React from "react";
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";

function Layout(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Preact has {props.stars} ⭐</p>
      <p> Why I couldn't get the above "props.star" ? </p>
    </div>
  );
}

Layout.getInitialProps = async () => {
  console.log("comes into layout getinitial props");
  const res = await fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/developit/preact");
  const json = await res.json(); // better use it inside try .. catch
  return { stars: json.stargazers_count };
};

export default Layout;
```

So as per the above given code, I have called the `layout` page inside `index.js` page (in my real application I need to call like this only so no changes in calling layout inside index)..

But when I made a `console.log()` in the function `Layout.getInitialProps` in layout, it doesn't print anything and hence the api data not fetched..

[**Complete working demo here with code**](https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-getinitialprops-4uig9)

Why can't I fetch the data inside the `layout.js` while calling as a children from `index.js`?

Also provide me the right updated solution to achieve this.. I really searched for many questions but none solved my issue and I couldn't understand those solutions clearly so please help me with the above given example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because  `getInitialProps` can only be added to the default component exported by a page, adding it to any other component won't work.
You should use `componentDidMount()` or `useEffect` instead, or move `getInitialProps` in the index and then pass the result to the component. something like (not tested) :

**index.js** :

```
import Layout from "./layout";
import React from "react";

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout />
        <h4> Main content will be displayed here !! </h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

**layout.js**

```
import React from "react";
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";
class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stars: false
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("comes into layout getinitial props");
    const res = await fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/developit/preact");
    const json = await res.json(); // better use it inside try .. catch
    this.setState({ stars: json.stargazers_count });
  }
  render() {
    const { stars } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Preact has {stars} ⭐</p>
        <p> Why I couldn't get the above "props.star" ? </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

**Edit:**
[Example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/nextjs-getinitialprops-1p5pq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) with class component
**Bonus:** If you want to add the layout for all the pages of your app this isn't the best approach, instead you should take a look to [custom _app.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app), [example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-app-layout/pages/_app.js)

Comment: Can you fork the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-getinitialprops-4uig9 and make your changes which will be helpful for me..

Comment: My requirement is I need to call the api which consists of data to be listed in the layout page like header menus, carousel, quick links, etc.., So i  need to fetch this api in layout page.. How could I achieve this?

Comment: If you don't mind can you create an example for the better approach which you have mentioned in the bonus part of your answer? I am new in next.js and react so It would be helpful for me if you offer help in the better approach witth codesandbox example..